# How to convert decimal value into integer

Tags: c#

I have a decimal value in a TextBox. I need to convert that value to an integer.

How can I do this using C#?

Comment: converting decimal to integer may result in loss of data. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: You can have idea about conversion at following link with all possible scenarios. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326756%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx):

```
decimal val = 3.13m;
int newval = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

But:
convert `decimal` to `int`  may loss of data.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link for more detail
[Decimal Implicit Conversion (Int32 to Decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131060%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Use this code:

```
decimal value = 3.14;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Int32.TryParse` (doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You are depending on user input, so just assuming that the value is correct might not be a good decision in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're talking about data in a TextBox, I assume that when you say "decimal" you just mean a base-10 number rather than a .NET Decimal value, which actually represents rational numbers rather than integers.  If you're converting user input to a numeric value then you should absolutely use the TryParse method of the appropriate type.  That will validate and, if possible, convert in one go.  If you want to convert to a 32-bit integer then Int32.TryParse is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Convert.ToInt32` from `mscorlib` as in

```
decimal value = 3.14m;
int n = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93kx4xke.aspx). You can also use `Decimal.ToInt32`. Again, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.toint32.aspx). Finally, you can do a direct cast as in

```
decimal value = 3.14m;
int n = (int) value;
```

which uses the explicit cast operator. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf02hx8s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to convert decimal value in a TextBox into integer

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox.Text);
```